# Worksheet Function Countifs for resizable range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in which I count the records through Worksheet.Function.Countif.

It is nice because it counts the rows using .Rows.Count and so I am alwasy ensured if my table changes the size.

It looks like that (subset of the code):

```
endrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 20).End(xlUp).Row
  ws1.Cells(6, 34).Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & .Range("U6:U" & endrow).Address & ",U6)"
```

I wish to write the the worksheet.function formula in the same way as above but for 'Countifs'. In excel, I would type it like that:
=COUNTIFS($U$6:$U$144;U6;$T$6:$T$144$;"<>"&T6)

How to write it in vba, using 'endrow' as in the first demonstarted code, i.e. without '144' as the last row but with '& endrow' ?
I was trying multiple times, but I cannot get it to work :/

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ws1.Cells(6, 34).Formula = "=COUNTIFS($U$6:$U$" & endrow & ",U6,$T$6:$T$" & endrow & "," & """" & "<>" & """" & "&T6" & ")"
```

Comment: Hi, It is almost there, but not yet. The cell 'T6' should change the rows relatively as it goes down. Now, the condition <>T6 is on each row through the column and it should be changing the rows as they go down. Any idea how to change that?

Comment: Perfect :) Thank you.

Comment: No prob, glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This formula gets the last row of column A:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))),ROW(A:A)),0)
```