# Using COUNTIF function for the flexible range on cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good morning,

I would like to use the COUNTIF function for the flexible cell range, based on the number of the row.

If my record OR533 is based on the row 4 as per the formula:

```
 =MATCH(A2,Tracker!A3:A4000)
```

then the value on my cell W7 is 4.

Now I would like to incorporate this cell value into the COUNTIF function.

My counting function looks like this:

```
 =COUNTIF(D3:D9,"Julian")
```

but in this event it counts from the row 1, which is D3.
I want now this function working from the row, where my record is based, which is 4 (D7 cell).

I tried to write:

```
 =COUNTIF(D3:(D9-4),"Julian")
 =COUNTIF(D3:(D&W7), "Julian")
```

None of them were working.

I found some solution in VBA

[Worksheet Function Countifs for resizable range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999094/worksheet-function-countifs-for-resizable-range)

but I am wondering is it possible to reach without VBA this time?
I would like to have the COUNTIF function working only to the specified row (marked in red on the image) instead of the last row.

[image]

Comment: You can do that through the volatile Indirect function, but better would be semi-volatile Index usage.

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: OFFSET is another way but it is also volatile, which may or may not matter in your situation.

Comment: I'm not behind a pc, but the syntax would be something like `=COUNTIF(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(....)):D9,....`

Comment: @JvdV - is it the only formula that will accept a colon in the middle? (sorry this is OT)

Comment: I would say there is no other function that would allow this besides INDIRECT, but then again, I'm not a 100% sure @SJR

Comment: @SJR `OFFSET`, `INDEX`, `XLOOKUP` (which is basically `INDEX` `MATCH` as a single, official function), `INDIRECT` - they all return *References* instead of *Values* (i.e. `ISREF(OFFSET(..))` would return `TRUE`).  `CHOOSE` can too, depending on what arguments you pass

Comment: @Chronocidal - belated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to follow-up on my comment. A semi-volatile way would be to use `INDEX`:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2,Tracker!A3:A4000)+3):D9,"Julian")
```

Beware that your use of `MATCH` currently might yield unwanted results. For an exact match include the last parameter > `MATCH(A2,Tracker!A3:A4000,0)`. Obviously you could also refer to `W7` if you so desire.

And if you want some background on volatile, semi-volatile and non-volatile you could have a read [here](https://www.fm-magazine.com/news/2019/jun/microsoft-excel-volatile-functions-201920646.html).

Comment: It returns N#A

Now I put the image into the question and modified it slightly. What I would like to have is the COUNTIF function working just to the specified row only (marked red) instead of the last row.

Comment: @MariuszKrukar If you use the 'Evaluate Formula' tool, *where* does it error?  (And, what is the value of cell W7?)

Comment: @MariuszKrukar, typically it would error out when `MATCH` can't validate the value from `A2` in your `Tracker!A3:A4000` reference. As mentioned by Chronocidal, helpfull would be to step through the formula and see what part returns the error.

Comment: So I did the evaluation formula and the tool underscored:
MATCH(4,A3:A9), where the 4 corresponds to my row number calculated in the cell W7.

Comment: `MATCH(4,A3:A9)` is never going to be any evaluation of the above formula. So I cannot replicate what you are talking about.

Comment: I would rather to use:
=COUNTIF(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(W7)):D9,"Matt Lewis")
but excel says, that I put too many arguments

Comment: That's a wrong construct, try: `=COUNTIF(INDEX(D:D,W7):D9,"Matt Lewis")` instead.

Comment: @MariuszKrukar `MATCH(4,A3:19)` won't work, because the values of A3:19 are `"OR1012"`, `"OR1013"`, `"OR322"`, `"OR533"`, `"OR645"`, `"OR650"` and `"OR813"`.  None of those are `4`, so there is no match

Comment: @Chronocidal, I guess `Tracker!` references another sheet?

Comment: @JvdV Ah, good catch:  From the screenshot, OP has *removed* the `Tracker!` when putting the code into their workbook

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @JvdV this is EXACTLY what I was after. Now I can swiftly change my COUNTIF range. 
For the opposite range it will be: =COUNTIF(INDEX(D:D,W7):D9,"Matt Lewis").